# Can executeQuery(String sql) function's return value be typecasted to a String Array?

Tags: java, sql, arrays, jdbc, resultset

I have the following Code :-

```
sql = "select Col3 from MyOption where OptionKey = (?,?,?,?) and ID = " + _Id;

pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1, "Mail.IMAP.Server");
pst.setString(2, "Mail.IMAP.Port");
pst.setString(3, "Mail.IMAP.AuthUser");
pst.setString(4, "Mail.IMAP.UseTLS");
```

Since my Code returns only a single column containing String, **can I type-cast the row to :-
String[] array = pst.executeQuery(); ?**

Because iterating a resultset and setting properties like properties.setProperty("mail.imap.host", rs.toString());

is really difficult.

Is there an easier solution here, to avoid iterating the whole array and checking it one by one ?

```
while (rs.next() && rs.toString().contains("imap")) {

int i = 1;

if(i==1)
properties.setProperty("mail.imap.host", rs.toString());
if(i==2)
properties.setProperty("mail.imap.port", rs.toString());
if(i==3)
properties.setProperty("mail.imap.auth", rs.toString());
if(i==4)
properties.setProperty("mail.imap.starttls.enable", rs.toString());
i++;
}
```

**Is there an easier way of Doing this ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to your question:
No, is not possible because (from PreparedStatement javadoc)

[ResultSet executeQuery() throws SQLException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery%28%29)

> Executes the SQL query in this PreparedStatement object and returns
>   the ResultSet object generated by the query.

and you can't change this signature.

Your intention is to return the whole `ResultSet` in `Array<>[]` variable and, for large resultset, this can results in a `OutOfMemoryException`.
You can think to use Spring JDBC support and [JDBCTemplate.queryForList()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForList%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) to make use of `ResultSet` mapping easy

EDIT:
About your code best choice is to change query as:

```
select Col3,MyOption from MyOption where OptionKey in (?,?,?,?) and ID = " + _Id";

while(rs.hasNext()) {
  String option = rs.getString(2);
  String optionValue = rs.getString(1);
  String propertyName = null;
  if(option.contains("imap")) {
    switch(options) {
      case "Mail.IMAP.Server":
        propertyName = "mail.imap.host";
        break;
      case "Mail.IMAP.Port":
        propertyName = "mail.imap.port";
        break;
      case "Mail.IMAP.AuthUser":
        propertyName = "mail.imap.auth";
        break;
      case "Mail.IMAP.UseTLS":
        propertyName = "mail.imap.starttls.enable";
        break;
    }
    if(null != propertyName) {
      properties.setProperty(propertyName, optionValue);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer would be more acceptable, **if you can suggest any other way of setting properties** 'if(i==2)
properties.setProperty("mail.imap.port", rs.toString());' or may be a **more elegant solution, to getting a property one by one.** Thanks in Advance